# visual studio: cannot get full list of properties of a build configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm writing extension for Visual Studio. And in my extension I want to access the build configuration properties of current project.

I've been able to get the Properties of the build configuration via DTE using following code:

```
        SelectedItems selections = dte.SelectedItems;
        int n = selections.Count;
        SelectedItem s;
        if (n > 0) {
            s = selections.Item(1);
            if (s.Project != null)
            {
                Configuration config = s.Project.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration;
                props = config.Properties;
            }
```

But the "props" object has only a portion of all properties of the build config. It lacks one property that I'm sure is there. So how can I get full list of properties of the active configuration ?

Thanks !

Comment: can you put some examples?

Comment: @LeiYang In target experiment instance of VS, create a Win32 application project. Select the project. After my code catches the selection event and get the project and active build configuration, the configuration.Properties contains only 23 properties. But In the Project properties dialog, we can see there are big number of options there, way more than 23.